# What to do against high Light Sensitivity?

Tags: eye, sunlight

Well, I would like to know if there is an way to decrease light sensitivity with Food/operations/technical help/change in Lifestyle or whatever.

I am highly sensitive to Light since years but it seems that it gets worser and worser. I already tried to "forcefully" go outside if there is a lot sunshine to "train" me to the sunlight, but it doesn´t help.

Nowadays I try to avoid as much sunlight as possible and go only outside at dusk/dawn but this is obviously not possible all day. The Sensivity goes that far that I am not even when it´s (a little bit) cloudy to look straight ahead, I always have to look down and already know at common streets all little stones.

I already asked my eye doctor and the only thing she said was: "Some are more sensitiv than others". And that although when I am on that stool and she is is investigating my eye with light I am barely able to sit still with that and afterwards I am full of tears.

btw: I have a high dioptries count and always changing glasses to sunglasses is extremely unpractical - who wants to run around with an 2nd Set of Glasses...?. Interestingly it is not that problematic if I am sitting in my car, but in some situations I already thought that it would have been better to stop the car to be safe.

Comment: What you are going through is clearly called photophobia

Comment: Guess I will then change my eye doctor if she is not even able to point that out....